# Dispay parent name in child id..instead of child id in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
category_id   name    parent_id   Action
1             pranav  0           Edit
2             shah    1(pranav)   Edit
3             bugle   2(shah)     Edit
```

Instead of parent id, I want to display name over there in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><?php echo $cat->parent_id; ?>
          <?php foreach ($category as $child): ?>
              if($cat->parent_id == $child->category_id)
                {
                  echo $child->name;
                  break;
                }
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is it your answer or extended part of your question?